# Ng-route not working (Offline)

Tags: angularjs, angular2-routing

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en-Us">
<head>
<title>Angular SPA</title>
<meta chafset ="UTF-8" meta name="viewport" content= "width=device-width, initial-scale= 1.0">
<link rel = 'stylesheet' href = 'style.css'/>
<script src = "angular-1.6.9\angular.min.js"></script>
<script src = "angular-1.6.9\angular-route.js"></script>
<script src= "trial.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app ="myApp">
It is a fact that the best programmers are: 
<p><a href ="#men">Men</a></P>
<p><a href ="#women">Women</a></P>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is is trial.js:

```
var ra = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
ra.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/men', {
template: '<h1>Of course, So true</h1>'})
.when('/women', {
templateUrl: 'test.html'});
}]);
```

This main problem is the routing is not working. Instead I get: http://localhost/set%201/#!#men without any change on the page. Am using Angular js 1.6.9 with all the code (folder contained) in the same directory as my index.html. Please help!

Comment: `angular2-routing` as a tag seems unnecessary

Comment: you have a slash: `.when('/men'` but you are not using it with links `<a href="#men">`, consider using `<a href="#!/men">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<p><a href ="/men">Men</a></p>
<p><a href ="/women">Women</a></p>
```

Comment: <a ng-href ="/men" > does not work...even if I remove the / still not working. Why?

Comment: @Xserge yeah, sorry, got it mixed up with `ui-sref` (using a better routing module `ui.router`). But `ng-href` should be used if you have something like `"#!/{{choice}}"`, which can change the value. Here is a [demo in a Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nJVbtEsoOaRSpAc2o0h2?p=preview) of what I mean